# Program that reads a vote text file and prints the outcome not printing the right numbers

Tags: python, text-files

Here is my code I need it to read a line of text that just composes of y's a's and n's y meaning yes n meaning no a meaning abstain, I'm trying to add up the number of yes votes. The text file looks like this:

```
Aberdeenshire  
yyynnnnynynyannnynynanynaanyna  
Midlothian  
nnnnynyynyanyaanynyanynnnanyna  
Berwickshire  
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnynnnnnynnnnny
```

here is my code:

```
def main():
    file = open("votes.txt")
    lines = file.readlines()

    votes = 0
    count = 0
    count_all = 0
    for m in range(1,len(lines),2):
        line = lines[m]
        for v in line:
            if v == 'a':
                votes += 1
            elif v == 'y':
                count_all += 1
                count += 1
                votes += 1
            else:
                count_all += 1

        print("percentage:" + (str(count/count_all)))

    print("Overall there were ", (count/count_all),"  yes votes")

main()
```

Comment: Consider adding the appropriate language tag.

Comment: Sorry new to the site.

Comment: Can you make it clear what the problem is and what you want to do? Right now you're just describing what you've done but we don't know what's wrong with it...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should note that your `file.readlines()` actually gives you the `\n` at the end of each line, which in your code will both be treated in the `else` block, so as no's:

```
>>> with open("votes.txt","r") as f:
...     print(f.readlines())
... 
['Aberdeenshire\n',
'yyynnnnynynyannnynynanynaanyna\n',
'Midlothian\n',
'nnnnynyynyanyaanynyanynnnanyna\n',
'Berwickshire\n',
'nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnynnnnnynnnnny\n']
```

So that might explain why you don't find the good numbers...

Now, to make the code a bit more efficient, we could look into the [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method of `str`, and maybe also get rid of those `\n` with a `split` rather than a `readlines`:

```
with open("votes.txt","r") as f:
    full = f.read()
    lines = full.split("\n")
    votes = 0
    a = 0
    y = 0
    n = 0
    for m in range(1,len(lines),2):
        line = lines[m]
        votes += len(line) # I'm counting n's as well here
        a += line.count("a")
        y += line.count("y")
        n += line.count("n")
    print("Overall, there were " + str(100 * y / (y + n)) + "% yes votes.")
```

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

More or less pythonic one liner, it doesn't give you the votes for each person/city tho:

```
from collections import Counter

l = """Aberdeenshire  
yyynnnnynynyannnynynanynaanyna  
Midlothian  
nnnnynyynyanyaanynyanynnnanyna  
Berwickshire  
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnynnnnnynnnnny"""

Counter([char for line in l.split('\n')[1::2] for char in line.strip()])
```

Returns:

```
Counter({'a': 11, 'n': 60, 'y': 22})
```

Comment: I made some small adjustments.